# Pygame - why my game repeats instead of closing?

Tags: python, function, loops, python-3.x, pygame

First of all, sorry for my noob question.

So I'm trying to learn pygame, and to do so I created a """game""' that is supposed to quit whenever someone clicks the close button ("x" button") in the top corner of the window, but instead the whole game restarts itself.
I use "Game = False" to point that the game needs to close, since everything that the game does is located in a loop that only starts with "Game = True", and at the end of the script (after the loop ends) there is a "pygame.quit()" and a "sys.exit()". This was was working fine, but recenlty I added the following lines:

```
if x < 0 or x > display_width - spacecore_width:
            game_over()
```

Those are supposed to call a "game_over" function, that resets the game by calling the another function that covers the whole game (the loop is located inside of this function). But this is not supposed to happen when someone clicks the "x" button to quit the game, and I have no idea of why this also happens when such thing is done (besides working as intended, by only repeating the game if "x < 0 or x > display_width - spacecore_width".

I already know how to avoid it (I just need to replace "Game = False" with those quit commands) but I would like to know why the problem happens in the first place.

Here's the full code:

```
import pygame, sys, time

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

pygame.display.set_caption("Não enconste nas bordas da tela") 

WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED = (255,0,0) 

SPACECORE = pygame.image.load("spacecore.png")

spacecore_width = 100

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def text_and_rect(text,font):
    text_surface = font.render(text,True,RED)
    return text_surface, text_surface.get_rect()


def message_display(text):
    font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",50)
    text_surf, text_rect = text_and_rect(text,font)
    text_rect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    DISPLAY.blit(text_surf,text_rect) 
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)   



def game_over():
    message_display("Você morreu de morte morrida")
    game_loop()


def player(x,y):
    DISPLAY.blit(SPACECORE,(x,y))



def game_loop():
    Game = True

    x = display_width * 0.5
    y = display_height * 0.8

    mod_x = mod_y = 0



    while Game == True:
        pygame.display.update()
        DISPLAY.fill(WHITE) 



        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                Game = False


            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    mod_x = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    mod_x = 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    mod_y = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    mod_y = 5


            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    mod_x = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    mod_y = 0

        x += mod_x
        y += mod_y

        clock.tick(60) 

        player(x,y)

        if x < 0 or x > display_width - spacecore_width:
            game_over()  



game_loop()
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: How about `break`ing after quit events to stop handling events?

Comment: @ Reut Sharabani 

I don't know why the conversation seens to have moved to another comment section, but anyways... 

I know I could use break as a workaround to quit the game, and the solutions you posted in your answer were very useful. What I don't understand is why does the game calls the function "gameover()" , which should not be called when quitting the game (since it actually restarts said game), if the condition for the "if" statment that calls it is never met (or it shouldn't be, at least for quitting the game).

Also, I couldn't get to debug my script (yes, I am THAT noob)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're breaking out of the loop and then calling the loop function again:

```
while Game == True:

    # some here code

    if x < 0 or x > display_width - spacecore_width:
        break # leave while loop

 # proceed elsewhere
game_over()
```

Or alternatively cut the flow back to `game_loop` in `game_over`:

```
def game_over():
    message_display("Você morreu de morte morrida")
    # game_loop() # removed
```

Currently you're never breaking out of loops when game is over - you're just calling other functions (which in turn active another loop) in a mutually-recursive manner, effectively this never ends any game.

Also, if you receive a quit event you may want to `break` out of the for loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Game = False
            break
```

Comment: I think you were right the first time, almost.  As I read the question, game_over() is supposed to print the message and start a new game.  There should be another place where the user can quit the app.    He should break from the loop in this case, but there should not be a call to game_over() after game_loop().

Comment: I think `game_loop` starts the new game, so effectively this creates a fine code. I don't see other "exit points" so to speak from the loop - so if you got there it is game over :-)

Comment: Sorry.  I skipped right over the line "Or alternatively, ..."

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I still don't understand why this happens when I try to close my game. Shouldn't the "game_over" only be interpreted IF the player pass thorugh the borders of the screen ("if x < 0 or x > display_width - spacecore_width:")? I understand that this does not ends any game (it justs call the function again), but I don't understand why this statment is taken in consideration when I try to quit, since the conditions are never met (and the game closes like normal whitout such statment)...

Comment: @enricogp before I dive into it again, did it solve the initial problem?

Comment: @Reut Sharabani Yes, it did. I just don't understand why it wasn't working before, since the if statment conditions were never completed...

Comment: @Reut Sharabani Also, why isn't the function "game_over" run whenever I try to quit the game? Because the "if" statment that indicates the game should close also ends the loop, so shouldn't "game_over()" be interpreted just like it did with the other "if" statment?

Comment: Are you sure the condition meets whenever you reach that point? If you're sure than why are you using an `if` statement and not what's inside of it? If the condition isn't met - it shouldn't execute. You can verify with a debugger or using print statements (less favorable).

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob, but how do I do any of those things? (I found an online debugger, but it's not compatible with pygame)

Comment: Use pycharm community edition, that's what I use and it's great: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/

Comment: Well, thanks for giving me a solution anyway, I think that the act of closing the game makes the game elements end up in the corner (the reason of why I put those lines inside of the if statment was because I did not want it to run unless the player crossed the game borders. That's cuz game_over restarts the game, and I didn't want that)